# Does google signin require cookie consent?

Tags: google-signin

Does Google One Tap or the Sign In With Google button powered by the latest libraries require a cookie banner before displaying or triggering?

Googles help is silent on the issue and I can find nothing on the subject.

Reddit for example display's a personalised button even if I reject cookies.

Comment: I would love to know this too!